# Thawed frozen dough

Tags: food-safety

I bought a Bridgford ready dough.  I kept it thawing in the refrigerator for a week. Is it safe to use this frozen dough that has been thawing in the refrigerator for a week?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a frozen bread dough, yeast based, yes, should be fine.

Comment: Yes, it's a frozen bread dough.  Thank you for the response.

Answer (score -1):

It'll be safe to eat, but after a week in the fridge it sure will be awful. The yeast will be ineffective/dead, the dough will be thickly skinned further inhibiting proof.

So it's not going to hurt you, but it will taste and look like ass.

Comment: Yeast can survive quite well in the fridge (after all, it can handle freezing and thrives at room temperature) and even proves slowly. A skin would only be an issue  if it was exposed to the air, and there's no reason to assume that.

Comment: Well.... After 2 decades in a commercial bakery, I would disagree completely that a yeast dough (and the yeast within) will survive just fine. And it only lasts in the freezer for a small while without chemical extenders. But what do I know?

Comment: While it is possible that it **could** be " awful " it is also possible that if your fridge is  cold enough then the yeast will be retarded enough to still provide leavening, especially if it went from the freezer to the fridge as it would take a while just to thaw.  If the loaf is in a sealed container and wrapped in plastic wrap, and it has sufficient leavening life left in it then it will not be awful.